# convert jsonString to list by GSON

Tags: android, arraylist, gson

I have converted a jsonArray to string :

```
[{"Key":"Comment","Value":"گواهی پایانکار با شماره ارجاع 2168439 صادر شد","Children":""},{"Key":"Version","Value":"BIZ.SC- Version=8.8.495.1","Children":""},{"Key":"lat","Value":"0","Children":""},{"Key":"lng","Value":"0","Children":""},{"Key":"District","Value":"11","Children":""},{"Key":"ScheduledMessage","Value":"{\"Id\":\"41b02583-1974-4f31-8ba1-c58d035f388b\",\"NotificationId\":\"53a23080-88cf-4256-855c-6ef2a51f2aab\",\"DistributionId\":\"98ee1d58-dd1e-4ef9-b82a-0af2a2a0e9ef\",\"CreationDateTime\":\"\\\/Date(1504277609736)\\\/\",\"ExpirationDateTime\":\"\\\/Date(4070908800000)\\\/\",\"Address\":\"Topics\/Notifications\/Global\",\"FileName\":\"\"}","Children":""}]
```

now I want convert it to pojo java class by Gson as a `List<EventData>`

```
List<EventData> result = GsonUtil.createGson().fromJson(eventArray,
new TypeToken<List<EventData>>() {}.getType());

notifyParcel.setEventData(result);
```

this is my pojo class:

```
public class EventData implements Serializable{
private List<Children> Children;
private String Key;
private String Value;

public List<Children> getChildren() {
    return Children;
}

public void setChildren(List<Children> children) {
    Children = children;
}

public String getKey() {
    return Key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    Key = key;
}

public String getValue() {
    return Value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    Value = value;
}
}
```

I go this error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JSON example `Children` defined as string: `"Children": ""`. But expects Array a.e. `[]`

To get rid of this error, you can replace `"Children": ""` with `"Children": []` or try to remove `"Children": ""` at all

Comment: I change to it : http://codepad.org/VDkjm3c4. but i got this error:`Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 87 path $[0].Children`

Comment: @sayres sorry mate, typo: it should be `[]` a.e.` "Children": []` : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=fcab865350cf520e66fb7212dac7da94

Comment: dude this is where I save this childlern:http://codepad.org/Ab9ONuiP . what can I exactly to do? I can not put [] without ""

Comment: @sayres instead to add "[]", add `new JSONArray()`